# Finding our way on buses in Ottawa and Winnipeg

Tags: canada, buses, ottawa, winnipeg

We live in London, and the buses have automated systems to let you know the name of the next bus stop ahead of time. This makes them really easy to use and very difficult to get lost.

We're going on holiday to Ottawa and Winnipeg for a couple of weeks, and it would make it an awful lot easier if there was something similar in place.

Do the buses in Ottawa and Winnipeg have any kind of automated system to let you know the names of upcoming bus stops?

Comment: I've been on buses in both cities, and don't recall any issues with going around the city.

Comment: Phone apps such as Moovit are designed for public transportation route-finding. They also tell you when you are a few stops from where you want to get off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the Ottawa buses feature this. The [OCTranspo accessibility page](http://www.octranspo.com/accessibility/accessibilty_features) includes:

> Automatic announcement of next stops over the speaker system inside the bus: [Next Stop Announcement System (NSAS)](http://www.octranspo.com/accessibility/next_stop_announcement_system_nsas)
>
> Audible exterior announcements of the route and destination of the arriving bus, from a speaker located outside its front door
>
> Visual display of the next stop, bus route, destination and time on a sign inside the bus

And yes, the Winnipeg buses also feature this. The [Winnipeg transit accessibility page](http://winnipegtransit.com/en/rider-guide/accessible-transit/) includes

> In 2009 the entire bus fleet had Audible Next Stop Announcers installed. NSA, as it is called for short, audibly announces the next stop as buses travel down the road. At the same time, an audible announcement is made a display located at the front of the bus shows the name of the next stop.
> This new system informs passengers of upcoming stops and is particularly helpful to passengers traveling to areas they are not familiar with, passengers traveling at night when street signs and landmarks are not as visible, as well as passengers with visual impairments or hearing impairments.

I find it interesting that this (no doubt expensive) system was installed in both places for accessibility reasons, and information about it is under "accessibility" in both places - this is the Canadian word for "things we do to make our system work for everyone". Clearly it has a large benefit to visitors and occasional riders as well.